# solr synonyms how to add a value having round brackets

Tags: solr

I have a value like below

```
(cat),dog
```

How can i add this entry in solr synonyms file, so that dog should match to (cat).

Comment: did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using `solr.SynonymFilterFactory`. You need to specify it in `schema.xm`l like this:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

Most likely, you have a problem, by using `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory`, which breaks tokens on `(` and `)`, in this case, I would recommend to use `solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`